# Time series analysis with R statistical software

Tags: r, datetime

I have a problem when analysing a dataset.

```
786650417, 3197478917, 264665794, **2016-12-01T00:00:00Z**, 1, 4, 94717580778
```

Above is one column in my data set.I want to extract the date and time (which is highlighted) and create a new column with that.

I have tried the following code:

```
sms <- sms %>%
  mutate(date =str_extract_all(data , "[0-9]+\\-"))
```

From this code, I got the date which is separated with (-), but not correctly.

```
sms <- sms %>%
  mutate(time =str_extract_all(data , "[0-9]+\\:"))
```

From this, I got the time.

Then, I removed the inverted commas using the below R code.

```
del <- colwise(function(sms) str_replace_all(sms, '\"', ""))
sms <- del(sms)
```

So, finally, it looked like this.

```
786650417, 3197478917, 264665794, 2016-12-01T00:00:00Z, 1, 4, 94717580778
```

I made two columns from the above row. Those two rows are below.

```
date                    time
c(2016-, 12-)       c(00:, 00:)
```

But now, I cannot perform any forecasting methods since the date and time are not in the correct format.

Please help me to extract the date and time as the right type from this record.

```
786650417, 3197478917, 264665794, 2016-12-01T00:00:00Z, 1, 4, 94717580778
```

In my dataset there are 2 million records like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this -

```
library(stringr)
library(chron)
df <- data.frame(raw_data=c("786650417,3197478917,264665794,2016-12-01T00:00:00Z,1,4,94717580778",
                            "786650417,3197478917,264665794,2016-12-01T00:02:17Z,1,4,94717580778",
                            "786650417,3197478917,264665794,2016-12-01T00:28:10Z,1,4,94717580778"))
df$date <- as.Date(str_extract(df$raw_data, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"))
df$time <- chron(times=str_extract(df$raw_data, "\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}"))
df$datetime <- strptime(paste(str_extract(df$raw_data, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"), str_extract(df$raw_data, "\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}"), sep = " "), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df
```

**note:** Time can be formatted as per the real timezone of collected data- you just need to give one more parameter to `strptime()` e.g. `tz = "GMT"` if timestamp is in GMT format or else by default your local system's timezone will be selected (as in this case it's IST).

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem by marking it as the right answer :)*

Comment: hi buddy I done according to your advise. for the above record it generates the date as "2016-12-01 IST" .. this is really cool. but how can i do this to all the records ( 2 million) and create a new column using that data.       &&&&& I did not get what you said with the time. How to filter the time like the date . Actually i am really grateful for you for supporting me.

Comment: Show us the desired sample o/p format by updating your original question.

Comment: [1] "2016-12-01 00:00:00 IST" "2016-12-01 00:02:17 IST" "2016-12-01 00:28:10 IST" "2016-12-01 01:17:02 IST"
[5] "2016-12-01 00:00:30 IST" "2016-12-01 00:06:17 IST"    This is what i get after applying your method for first 6 records. This is going quite well..  && now i can perform this to my entire dataset. that is okay. next thing is to create a two new column putting date and time for each column.. let us go for that now.

Comment: sms.head1$Date_Time <-as.Date(paste(solu , sep = "-"))   i got the new date column using the above command. finally it is up to time. since i want to analyse hourly data i desperately need the time column. so please help me to achieve this

Comment: I updated answer as per your revised requirement. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much buddy. This is so clear and cool. You are a genius. Thanks again. Cheers!!!!

Comment: glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can assign the two columns you want to extract to a variable:

```
A <- nameOfYourSet$date 

B <- nameOfYOurSet$time
```

Use `$` to precise which label (which columns in your case) you want to consider.

Then try to use the `cbind()` function to do some concatenation to get what you want:

`cbind(A,B)` will "paste" `B` on the right side of `A`.

Finally, use as`.***()` functions to get the right format you need in order to perform forecasting (I don't know what format you need).

Comment: Thank you very much buddy. but this method did not worked for me.